# React Router on client side works only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'm using react-router for both server and client sided routing in an attempt to make an isomorphic app. The server routing works fine and I'm able to retrieve the data okay, However, on the client, the first link I click makes a call to react-router's callback on url change. Subsequent clicks do not trigger the callback for some reason.

```
//server.js
ReactRouter.run(mainApp.getComponent(), req.path, function (Root, state) {
//if no matching routes found, then go to 404
if (state.routes.length === 0) {
  res.status(404);
}

var RootComponent = fluxibleAddons.provideContext(Root, {
  getStore : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  executeAction : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
});

var loadAction = state.routes[1].handler.loadAction;
var renderReactOnServer = function () {
    var markup = React.renderToString(React.createElement(RootComponent, React.__spread({}, state, { context : context.getComponentContext()  }) ));
    res.expose(mainApp.dehydrate(context), mainApp.uid);

    console.log("Rendering Server React Components");
  res.render("index", {
    main: markup,
    uid: mainApp.uid
  }, function (err, markup){
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }
    res.send(markup);
  });
};

if (loadAction){
  context.getActionContext().executeAction(loadAction, { params: state.params, query: state.query }, renderReactOnServer);
} else {
  renderReactOnServer();
}
```

I'm running react router's main run method in my server.

On the client I'm running the following

```
Router.run(app.getComponent(), Router.HistoryLocation, function (Root, state) {
        var RootComponent = fluxibleAddons.provideContext(Root,{
            getStore : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
        });
        React.render(React.createElement(RootComponent, React.__spread({}, state, { context : context.getComponentContext()  })), document.getElementById(app.uid));
 });
```

In my client.js, react router run's callback is called ONLY once, which is weird to me. There are no visible errors. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example of the link you're calling?

Comment: I figured it out, you can't create a new component on top of root component provided by react router, or else the root component will be unmounted each time stopping the router. However I still needed to pass the context to children, so what I did was I passed the context to the next highest component after Root, which is my app component, then app component passes context to all the children, which are route handlers